# What are these fancy icons in HTML called?

Tags: html

I see some websites use fancy icons. An example is this curly leaf icon at [Dive Into HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.info/past.html):

> ❧

I would like to know the formal name of these icons. I've tried searching "html entities" and "html glyphs" in Google but the results always show the boring old arrows and Greek characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a *unicode character*.

If you are using UTF-8 encoding - which the example site is - you have a very large range of characters you can use - not just arrows and greek characters.

I'd encourage you to use Firebug or some other developer inspector in your browser. It makes it very easy to reverse engineer things like this.

Comment: Is there a more specific classification of the "cooler" unicode characters? That is, the ones that look like objects and are not some letter from an alphabet. I searched "cool unicode characters" on Google and found some, but I'm wondering if I'm missing out on the even cooler ones with my poor nomenclature.

Comment: UTF-8 supports thousands of characters across many languages with glyphs in between. Searching for the *cooler* ones is subjective. That's to say your guess is as good as mine. Did you look at the link in **Dark Falcon**'s answer?

Answer (score 1):

These don't have any particular name as far as I know, they are simply Unicode glyphs. Here is a [table](http://www.atm.ox.ac.uk/user/iwi/charmap.html).